# Parse.com data fetch `NULL` value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i am newbie to parse.com and try very more time to fetch data from it but give `NULL` value each time. Here, in my Parse table contain 1.89k rows so i want to check all row and Fetch data from it. for data fetch i write a code like as

```
-(void)getdata
{
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSUInteger limit = 1000;
__block NSUInteger skip = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Business"];
[query whereKey:@"Admin" equalTo:self.bisusername];
[query setLimit: limit];
[query setSkip: skip];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        if (objects.count == limit) {
            skip += limit;
            [query setSkip: skip];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                self.qpinname=[allObjects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
                NSLog(@"Qpin Array %lu",(unsigned long)[self.qpinname count]);
                self.locationArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Location"];
                self.latitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
                self.longitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
                self.address=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Address"];
                self.usernameArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
                self.buildingNameArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"BuildingName"];
                self.businessHourArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"OfficeTiming"];
                self.parkingInfoArry=[allObjects valueForKey:@"Parking"];
                self.officenoArray=[allObjects valueForKey:@"DoorNumber"];
                NSLog(@"Office Array %@",self.officenoArray);
              hudView.hidden=TRUE;
            }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

and when i write a code like as

```
-(void)getdata
 {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"Type" equalTo:@"Business"];
[query whereKey:@"Admin" equalTo:self.bisusername];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        self.qpinname=[objects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
        self.locationArray=[objects valueForKey:@"Location"];
        self.latitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];
        self.longitude=[self.locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];
        self.address=[objects valueForKey:@"Address"];
        self.usernameArray=[objects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
        self.buildingNameArray=[objects valueForKey:@"BuildingName"];
        self.businessHourArray=[objects valueForKey:@"OfficeTiming"];
        self.parkingInfoArry=[objects valueForKey:@"Parking"];
        self.officenoArray=[objects valueForKey:@"DoorNumber"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
    }
}];
}
```

Then i got Value from table but it give me value from only one page i want to value from my whole table please give me solution for it
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't iterating the objects array at all. You are doing something like this:

```
self.qpinname=[allObjects valueForKey:@"GPIN"];
```

allObjects is an ARRAY not a dictionary. You need to iterate the array and access objects that way. Remember that objects are of the type PFObject that are downloaded from Parse.com. e.g.:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                for(PFObject *object in allObjects) {

                //now you can access things,e.g....
                self.locationArray=object[@"Location"]; 
                //and so on...



               }

            }];
```

That should fix it. Make sure you are using PFObject above in the loop too.